# Do I need to manually set $VIMRUNTIME on my pc

Tags: windows, vim

For me I think the following is the case:

```
$VIMRUNTIME='C:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim73'
```

But if I look in the pc's environment variables (via Computer>Properties etc) I cannot see this path - should I add it manually?

`_vimrc` currently looks like the following:

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

set diffexpr=MyDiff()

" Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode
:nnoremap <C-S>     :<C-U>update<CR>
:vnoremap <C-S>     :<C-U>update<CR>gv
:cnoremap <C-S>     <C-C>:update<CR>
:inoremap <C-S>     <C-O>:update<CR>

function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let eq = ''
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
      let eq = '"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `$VIMRUNTIME` is a special environment variable that automatically gets set by Vim.

`:help $VIMRUNTIME` would have already told you this:

> You don't normally set $VIMRUNTIME yourself, but let Vim figure it out.

Learn how the excellent and comprehensive `:help` is structured; all the information is in there (you just need to know how to find it)!

Comment: And you can see its value by doing `:echo $vimruntime`

Comment: +1 thanks again Ingo - I'm trying to use the help but there's quite a learning curve to using the help!

Answer (score 3):

Though vim helpfiles describe $VIMRUNTIME as an environment variable, you may find that it is not set in your shell.

It should be set in Vim, and you should be able to see it, *in Vim*, thus:

```
:echo $VIMRUNTIME
```

The ever-so helpful Vim helpfiles don't explain this.

But they do describe in exhausting detail the steps Vim goes through to derive a value for $VIMRUNTIME in its own, er, runtime environment.

If you are blessed with some form of obsessive compulsion, you might read far enough through this dense help text to see, at the very bottom, where it says that if want $VIMRUNTIME in your shell, you can get it with the following command:

```
VIMRUNTIME=`vim -e -T dumb --cmd 'exe "set t_cm=\<C-M>"|echo $VIMRUNTIME|quit' | tr -d '\015' `
```

Despite appearances, this is not some sort of joke. I repeat:

```
VIMRUNTIME=`vim -e -T dumb --cmd 'exe "set t_cm=\<C-M>"|echo $VIMRUNTIME|quit' | tr -d '\015' `
```